On which empires did the sun never set?
On which empires has it been true that “the sun never sets”? (I.e. at any point in the year, there is at least one place on a land that is widely recognized as being under de facto control of that country where the sun is above the horizon. I suppose there's a symbolic bonus if it remains true even during total solar eclipses.)
This was a widely reported aspect of the Spanish empire, and later of the British empire. Strangely, hardly anyone mentions the phrase in relation to their rivals, the Portuguese empire and the French empire.
Today, as far as I know, the countries (inclusive of all dependencies) where the sun never set are the United Kingdom (but not for much longer after the Chagos handover) and France. Norway comes close thanks to Bouvet Island if you allow twilight, but not for a strict definition of sunset, even if you include Antarctic claims (which I wouldn't).
Was there a time when the sun never set on the Portuguese empire? On the Dutch empire? On the Danish empire? Are there any other contenders?
Bonus (which I'm not sure is answerable): is there any historical explanation as to why the social consciousness of “the sun never sets” is so prevalent about the Spanish and British empire and not at all about other empires?

The first part of your question is pretty simple to answer. 15 degrees of longitudinal displacement corresponds to about an hour's time displacement. Assuming, conservatively, that sunlight lasts from 8am to 4pm, that means a country must have territories at least every 120 degrees of longitude around the globe for the sun to "never set". So take your favourite empire, find a map of it and start counting. Anyone who doesn't have territory in the Americas or the Pacific along with Western Africa/Europe fails immediately, so from memory, the only contenders are the French, Portuguese and Dutch.

For the second part, my above comment already shows that the number of empires to ever reach this size is very small. Of these, the Portuguese and the Dutch, assuming they even make the cut, had relative little territory, so similar to the US who reaches the "sun never sets" status if we count military bases, this aspect of their existence is not considered substantial enough to "brag about". Meanwhile, the French Empire existed in the shadow of the British, which was far larger, far more influential and far more significant. Compare these to the British and the Spanish...

The British empire is the largest empire to have ever existed in terms of land area encompassed, while the Spanish was the first empire in history to ever be able to claim that "the sun never sets" on it. In my opinion it is not surprising that this phrase (which was first propagated by the Spanish themselves) has come to be associated with the British and the Spanish empires but not the others.
Note: These comments are not an answer because I have no sources to back up what I just said, and I don't intend on finding any.

@Borealis You should make this an answer. People can't vote on comments.

@Borealis It's not just about the size but about the spread. The Mongol empire was very large, but was a land empire firmly rooted in one hemisphere. The Danish empire at its height controlled very little land outside the North Atlantic, but claimed trading posts at least in the Caribbean and in India — but I don't know if it reached far enough east towards the Pacific.

The French do, in French.  https://lenouveauconservateur.org/rubriques/politique-etrangere/richard-labeviere-la-france-est-le-seul-pays-du-monde-sur-lequel-le-soleil-ne-se-couche-jamais/

@cmw I thought answers had to have sources on this site? Like I said, I didn't make the comments an answer because I don't have any sources to support my assertions in the second half and don't intend on finding any. I also feel like my first comment isn't "answer material"; I didn't actually use my method to check which empires are applicable, I just stated an easy method to use.

@Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Yeah, that's what I said. To account for winter sunlight hours being shorter, if you only allocate 8 hours of sunlight per day, that gives you a sufficient spread to basically guarantee the "sun never sets" title. And yes, the Mongols fail because they didn't have land in the Americas or the Pacific, just like I said. That they were only present in the Northern Hemisphere would be irrelevant if they had land at the correct spread.

@Borealis Plenty (too many) posts here lack sources. But a map or diagram showing what you're saying would actually make for a pretty strong starting post. You could also do CW so that others can edit it to add any contenders (if you're not inclined to do that yourself). Just ideas. Comments are typically reserved for clarification issues. StackExchange isn't conducive to just general discussion (for better or for worse).

@Borealis Or to state this otherwise, somewhere in the world, of the 24 major time zones (each with 15 degrees), they have a possession where it is high noon.

As per @cmw's comment, I'll make my 3 comments into an answer. However, I again emphasise that I do not have any sources on hand to support my assertions for the second half of this answer; these are simply my own thoughts on the matter.

The first part of your question is pretty simple to answer. 15 degrees of longitudinal displacement corresponds to about an hour's time displacement. Assuming, conservatively, that sunlight lasts from 8am to 4pm (this avoids questions of "but what if it's winter/summer?" etc.), that means a country must have territories at least every 120 degrees of longitude around the globe for the sun to "never set". So take your favourite empire, find a map of it and start counting. Anyone who doesn't have territory in the Americas or the Pacific along with Western Africa/Europe fails immediately, so from memory, the only contenders are the French, Portuguese and Dutch.
Indeed, based on @Italian Philosopher's comment, the French (Colonial) Empire seems to satisfy the requirements, and looking at a map of it this seems plausible. To show an empire for which the claim is not true, consider the Russian Empire at its peak. It's Eastern-most edge was the Eastern-most point of modern day Alaska, so counting 120 degrees of longitude from this point, we end up just off the coast of Ireland. Within this area, the Russian Empire had no territory, and so it does not qualify for the "sun never sets" title:

For the second part of your question, the first part of my answer already makes evident that the portion of empires to ever qualify for this title is negligible. There are only 5, even potential, candidates (slightly more if you allow technicalities like twilight for Norway), two of which (Dutch and Portuguese) only just qualify with minor holdings around the globe. For these two (assuming they do qualify), wide-scale acknowledgement of "the sun never sets" title is not to be expected.
It seems the French Empire qualifies, but they had the unfortunate historical circumstance of existing at the same time as the British Empire, which was far larger, more influential and more significant (just in terms of the area, the British Empire was over twice the size). Consequently, remembrance of the French Empire in the same "manner" as the British, as the empire on which the sun never sets, again cannot be expected (and indeed, hasn't happened). Any such potential historical grandeur of the French Empire has been crushed by the far greater achievements of the British Empire.
This historical significance of the British Empire also serves to explain it's continued remembrance as the empire on which the sun never sets; in my opinion, this is a fitting title for the largest empire the world has ever seen.
Finally, the Spanish Empire was the first in history for which this moniker was applicable, and indeed the phrase itself originates from Habsburg writings on their own holdings. Due to it being the first, it has managed to retain the title even though it too is overshadowed by the British.

As an aside, I would like to mention that whether "the world" collectively assigns this title to an empire does not necessarily reflect it's usage within that country (see @Italian Philosopher's comment, for instance). The Romans and the Ancient Egyptians both made regular reference to their nation being one on which "the sun never sets" (or some similar phrase) and various other exaggerations regarding size can be found in many countries' histories.

If you count claims, both the Portuguese and Spanish Empires count - as the Pope granted them half of the world, they owned both poles, which are never in darkness at the same time

@SPavel Why would we count claims? I have never heard an argument for considering the territory of an empire to be the territory encompassed by its claims. Also, the Spanish count anyway; you don't need claims for that.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_empire_on_which_the_sun_never_sets (linked in the question), the moniker was not invented by the Spanish, but by an Italian and for a German emperor.

Also those ancient phrases from the wp article do not really seem equivalent, just similar because they are about sunshine? Ancients: "Everything under the sun is ours", Spaniards: "In our empire there is always sunshine somewhere"?

@Jan There are various opinions on where the phrase originated, however all agree that it was first used regarding the Habsburg Empire, which only allowed itself this title due to the Spanish possessions it then (briefly) possessed, and that it was invented/first used by a denizen of this empire (or at least the HRE). I suppose "Spanish" may thus be misleading here,  however this portion of the Habsburg Monarchy's history is often referred to as the "Spanish Empire" (e.g. by J. H Elliott in his aptly named "Imperial Spain"). I'll change it to "Habsburg writings".

@Jan Looking at the article you linked, an exemplar phrase given is "from the rising to the setting sun" when referring to the Roman Empire. I feel this is quite similar to "the sun never sets". Similarly for the quote from Xerxes: "The sun will then shine on no land beyond our borders." I think the message is quite similar: "Our empire encompasses all the world". The fact these phrases appear on the wikipedia page you linked only reinforces that others are of a similar opinion.

"The sun will shine on no land beyond our borders" a) is false if there are other empires, and b) stays true if the sun does not shine at all (e.g. on a flat earth). "In our empire the sun never sets" a) stays true if there are other empires, and b) is false if the sun does not shine at all.

@Jan I was going to say that I didn't say they are equivalent, but then realised I did. I have edited the answer to say "similar".

It is never night in Norway* (*though the sun does set)
Civil twilight is defined as the period when the sun is less than 6 degrees below the horizon:

As the Earth's atmosphere scatters and reflects much of the Sun's rays, coloring the sky bright yellow and orange, artificial lighting is generally not required in clear weather conditions to carry out most outdoor activities. Only the brightest stars and planets, like Venus and Jupiter, can be seen with the naked eye.

In the far North (and south), the period of twilight is very long because the path of the Sun in the sky is very flat.
Norway claims Queen Maud land in Antarctica, even if the claim is "frozen" (metaphorically) by the Antarctic Treaty. The Southern border of the claim has historically been seen as "undefined" (hard to find sources on this, but I believe it was because Norway did not want to claim a sector / pie slice of Antarctica as it was opposed to pie-sliced claims in the Arctic), but it goes arbitrarily close to the South Pole.
On the South Pole, civil twilight begins on 8 September and ends on 4 April.
The northernmost point in Norway is Ross Island, in Svalbard. Here 24-hour civil twilight begins on 29 March and ends on 13 September.
Hence, it is always at least civil twilight somewhere in Norway, based on the claims made by the Norwegian government as of 2024. At any point in time, you can stand on Norwegian land and it will be sufficient sunlight for you not to be able to see the stars.
What about daylight? For how long does the sun set on the Norwegian empire?
The westernmost point of Arctic Norway is Høybergodden, on Jan Mayen Island. The easternmost point is Kræmerpynten, on Svalbard.
There is 24-hour sunlight on the South Pole from 21 September to 20 March. There is 24-hour sunlight on Rossøya from 11 April to 31 August. Hence, there is a period from 20 March to 11 April in the spring and from 31 August to 21 September in the fall when the sun does set on Norway. For how long?
On 20th March, the sun rises on Kræmerpynten in the east at 04:34 and sets on Høybergodden in the west at 19:56.
But wait: Norway also claims Peter I Island in the south Pacific, where the sun rises at 9:02 and sets at 21:15 local time, which should correspond to 13:02 - 01:15 Norwegian time. Hence, on 20th March, there is no sun on Norwegian claims between 01:15 and 04:34 in the morning, Norwegian time. As the spring progresses, days become shorter in Peter I Island but longer in the North, on average I think the darkness period is shorter each day until midnight sun is present on 11th April.
Calculations for the fall are left as an exercise for the reader.
What about historically?
Norway claimed the Sverdrup Islands in Canada until 1930, which is very far to the west. The claim to Queen Maud land was not established until 1939, but the claim on Bouvet Island was in place. However, even if all claims had been active at the same time, I was not able to find a pattern where the sun never set on the Norwegian empire in the weeks around the spring and fall equinox. Even with Sverdrup Islands the east-west range is too short.
Norway never claimed Franz Josef Land during the period of Arctic imperialism (late 19th cent - 1930s), though conceivably they could have done. I did not check whether this would have given continuous daylight.
Conclusion
After careful calculation, Norway cannot be added to the list of empires where the sun never sets, but it's not that far off.
What about other Arctic/Antarctic countries?
Countries have to have claims both in the far North and far South to be able to have continuous sunlight or twilight in this way.

The other Arctic countries (Canada, USA, Russia, Greenland/Denmark) have not established claims in Antarctica
Of the countries that have established Antarctic claims (Argentina, Australia, Chile, France, New Zealand, Norway and the United Kingdom) only Norway has claims in the Arctic. United Kingdom is probably the second most northern, but it is already established in the premise of the original question that the sun never sets on the British Empire even when disregarding its Antarctic claims, so this does not add anything new.

Note
All dates for 2024 from timeanddate.com. All clock times given in or converted to Norwegian time, DST depending on time of year and definitions for 2024.


On which empires did the sun never set?
This was a widely reported aspect of the Spanish empire, and later of the British empire.

If you take it literally (i.e. an empire that has a possession in each of the 24 major time zones of 15 degrees at the same time) then only the British Empire would really qualify.
The Spanish Empire, at its furthest extent (in 1790) had no possessions between Italy and the Philippines (around 7 consecutive time zones).



British Empire (1901)Spanish Empire (1790)












Was there a time when the sun never set on the Portuguese empire? On the Dutch empire? On the Danish empire? Are there any other contenders?

France's empire would span many time zones, but not during a common period.



French Empire (1813, 1830-1960)Portuguese Empire (1415-1999)











At some point you will then find combinations of possessions and trading posts, which sometimes were shared with other countries.



Dutch Empire (1602–1975)Danish Empire (1536–1953)












Sources:

List of largest empires - Wikipedia

British Empire | History, Countries, Map, Size, & Facts | Britannica
Spanish Empire - Wikipedia




This doesn't seem to answer the question. I don't understand why you're bringing up time zones. The claim is about the position of the sun. Presence in multiple time zones is necessary, but not at 1 hour granularity. And it's not sufficient (e.g. if Russia built and claimed an island at the North Pole, or if the US formally annexed the South Pole, they could claim 24 time zones, but the sun would still set in the winter). The maps are part of the answer, but are they synchronous? Do the lighter parts denote credible claims to being part of the empire or just some kind of embassy?

@Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' 'I don't understand why you're bringing up time zones.' Then educate yourself. Every 15 degrees, at 12 noon the sun it at its highest ('the sun has not set') and if a Colonial Office recieves 24 telegrams (sent at 12 PM localy, but in GMT are 24 distinct hours) then that is a sign that it is an empire where 'the sun never set'.

@Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' This is an history forum (not a 'in my imagination a colony could have existed on the North/South pole and' if one country had a colony on both poles' this would be possible'), thus facts/knowlage are required. The provided maps show that this was possible for the Britsch Emprire, but not for the other named. The provided maps show that this was possible for the Britsch Emprire, but not for the other named.

What does the sun being at it highest less than 7.5° of longitude away have anything to do with the sun being above the horizon? Why would arbitrary boundaries (every 15° following an arbitrary origin) matter? How do the maps show that neither the Spanish empire nor the French empire fit the criterion “the sun never set”?
